# encode.bat not found in local ODI setup in Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I installed Oracle ODI 12c Studio in standalone mode.

My installation does not have **encode.bat** and **decode.bat** files included, and I now require these to encode SFTP passwords.

Is it possible to get these files without re-installing Oracle ODI entirely? Even if I obtained the files, would they work correctly without a full Oracle ODI installation?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3967954) will help you.
Extract from the website:

> .. The encoding of the password is done using weblogic encoding (for ODI 12c) and not the former ODI encoding (encode.bat/.sh) which is only for odi 11g ..